# I have a large multi line text file, read the line contents into a bash variable until a specific character(terminator)

Tags: bash, unix

Say I have a File with below contents, there is no format, but the field separator is ";"

```
This is  one field
on a line 
with some characters;
This is  one field 
on a line with some characters;
This is  one field on a line with some characters;
```

Assign field to a variable like this.
VAR="This is  one field 
on a line 
with some characters"

Tried the following code

```
IFS=';'
while read -r line
do
VAR="$line" 
done < "$file"
```

But the VAR contains only "This is  one field "
It is not using IFS=; and only picks each line with a new line.

Comment: There should be a dupe but I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while IFS= read -r -d ';' field; do
    printf '\n[FIELD]\n%s\n' "$field"
done <"$file"
```

- The `-d` option to `read` causes it to use `;` instead of [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) as the "line" terminator.
- `IFS=`, which sets `IFS` to the empty string, causes each "line" to be treated as a single field.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for excellent information about reading from files in Bash.